# Installing Windows 7 from DVD on iMAC without ISO

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, boot, boot-camp

I have:

```
iMAC (Retina 5K, 27-inch Late 2015)
Processor:    4GHz Intel Core i7
Memory:       16GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Startup Disk: Macintosh HD
Graphics:     AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4096 MB
OS:           macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1
```

I also have a PC with an i7 running Windows 10, this system is failing and I want to migrate the Windows dependant over to a Windows partition on the MAC using Boot Camp.

I have the original Windows 7 DVD which I installed the Windows System on before I upgraded to Windows 10.

How do I install Windows 7 from the DVD using Boot Camp? I tried to follow a Youtube video but it must be older because the instructions and software is different.

On my iMAC the OS is an ISO file, I inserted the Windows 7 DVD and selected the autorun.inf as I couldn't see and ISO and I'm not sure how I would obtain one. But I and then told by the Boot Camp Assistant:

```
Need 64-bit Windows 10 or later ISO file.
```

Comment: You cannot migrate the Windows 10 Free Upgrade to a different PC.

Comment: Do you need it to be Windows, or do you just need the data? See https://support.apple.com/HT204087 for how to just migrate it to the Mac itself

Comment: @Daniel B, I don't want to migrate the Windows 10 Free Upgrade, I just want to install Windows 7 so I can use the tools on my MAC.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Yes, I need to run some legacy Windows applications on the MAC, which I can do to a limited extent with Wine, but I was thinking it might be easier to set-up a virtual machine.

Comment: Your easiest method would be to actually put Win10 on it, as that's all that's supported for a '15 MBP. Well, Win8 is, but no-one would do that ;) https://support.apple.com/HT201468 has the full instrs. [You'd have to buy it to run it, same as you would WIn7, MS licenses are not transferable generally between machines, unlike Apple] Get the iso from MS, point Boot Camp at it & it will make a USB key which will then work to install Win inside BC.

Comment: @Tetsujin, can I download an ISO of Windows 10 from Microsoft? Thank you, for your help.

Comment: It's pretty much the only way these days. if you buy a boxed copy all you're really buying is the serial number. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: Ok, I downloaded Win10_1607_English_x64.iso, launched Boot Camp Assistant and selected the ISO, I set the partition size to 300GB, however when I clicked on the Install button I get an error dialog "Need 64-bit Windows 10 or later ISO file."